# Installing Windows 7 alongside Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, windows, windows-7, windows-8

I have windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04 installed, and I was wondering if it is possible to install also Windows 7 not by downgrading Windows 8.1 to Windows 7, but to have Windows 8.1, Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04 installed.

Is there any way to do it?

Thank you for answering!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can triple boot Windows 7, Windows 8 and Ubuntu provided you have enough space for three OS. You have to create separate partition for Windows 7 in the unallocated space along with the remaining space available in the hard disk. If no space is available then you have to delete an existing partition to install Windows 7.